# jQuery background-position animation moves in the opposite direction on first hover

Tags: jquery

When I perform the very first hover on a div of class '.tile' in Chrome (Windows 8), the background-position, while specified to have only a negative shift, retreats in the opposite direction. This behavior is repeated on the first hover for every such div; however, it does not seem to repeat itself on subsequent hovers, sliding smoothly with no stutter.

I have tried removing the padding as suggested in some older jQuery animation stuttering FAQs, to no avail (though I suppose they no longer apply to jQ 1.3+?). I'm new to jQuery and could use a little help, thanks. :)

```
$(function() {
    $('.tile').hover(function () {
        console.log('in');
        $(this).animate({
            'background-position-y': -($(this).children('figcaption').height())
        }, 'fast', 'linear');
        $(this).children('figcaption').slideToggle('fast');
    },
    function () {
        console.log('out');
        $(this).animate({
            'background-position-y': 0
        }, 'fast', 'linear');
        $(this).children('figcaption').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks like this is a problem with how I'm dealing with background-position-y values, not a jQuery problem. Looking into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that since I did not know the height of my background images, it would be impossible to specify an offset from the center due to css background-position rules.

I went ahead and used an image resizing script ([SLIR](https://github.com/lencioni/SLIR)) to crop it into shape. Knowing the dimensions of the resulting image, I could use an absolute value to position my background as required.

**References:**

- [CSS: Using Percentages in Background-Image](http://www.sitepoint.com/css-using-percentages-in-background-image/)